# Mathematical precision at 19th decimal place and beyond

Tags: math, precision, raku

I have the same set of data and am running the same code, but sometimes I get different results at the 19th decimal place and beyond. Although this is not a great concern to me for numbers less than 0.0001, it makes me wonder whether 19th decimal place is Raku's limit of precision?

```
     Word 104 differ: 
             0.04948872986571077     19 chars 
             0.04948872986571079     19 chars
     Word 105 differ: 
             0.004052062278212545    20 chars 
             0.0040520622782125445   21 chars
```

Comment: What number type are you using?

Comment: IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point numbers have 15-17 decimal digits precision and the numbers you list have no more than that (the leading zeros are not important).

Comment: Thank you user0721090601 and Martin Liversage. I have no specifically declared number types. The data are from the internet and are mixes of Int, Cool, fractions, and scientific notations. So, I think Raku defaults to float, and so 15-17 decimal positions. Thank you for this clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** See the doc's outstanding [Numerics](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics) page.

---

(I had forgotten about that page before I wrote the following answer. Consider this answer at best a brief summary of a few aspects of that page.)

---

There are two aspects to this. Internal precision and printing precision.

## 100% *internal* precision until RAM is exhausted

Raku supports arbitrary precision number types. Quoting [Wikipedia's relevant page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic):

> digits of precision are limited only by the available memory of the host system

You can direct Raku to use one of its arbitrary precision types.<sup>**[1]**</sup> If you do so it will retain 100% precision until it runs out of RAM.

| Arbitrary precision type | Corresponding type checking<sup>**[2]**</sup> | Example of value of that type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`Int`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Int) | `my Int $foo ...` | `66174449004242214902112876935633591964790957800362273` |
| [`FatRat`](https://docs.raku.org/type/FatRat) | `my FatRat $foo ...` | `66174449004242214902112876935633591964790957800362273 / 13234889800848443102075932929798260216894990083844716` |

Thus you can get arbitrary *internal* precision for integers and fractions (including arbitrary precision decimals).

## *Limited* internal precision

If you do not direct Raku to use an arbitrary precision number type it will do its best but may ultimately switch to limited precision. For example, Raku will give up on 100% precision if a formula you use calculates a [`Rat`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Rat) and the number's denominator exceeds 64 bits.<sup>**[1]**</sup>

Raku's fall back limited precision number type is [`Num`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Num):

> On most platforms, [a `Num` is] an IEEE 754 64-bit floating point numbers, aka "double precision".

Quoting [the Wikipedia page for that standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

> Floating point is used ... when a wider range is needed ... even if at the cost of precision.

> The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision (2−53 ≈ 1.11 × 10−16).

## *Printing* precision

Separate from internal precision is stringification of numbers.

(It was at this stage that I remembered the doc page on Numerics linked at the start of this answer.)

Quoting [Printing rationals](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics#Printing_rationals):

> Keep in mind that output routines like `say` or `put` ... may choose to display a `Num` as an `Int` or a `Rat` number. For a more definitive string to output, use the `raku` method or [for a rational number] `.nude`

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> You control the type of a numeric expression via the types of individual numbers in the expression, and the types of the results of numeric operations, which in turn depend on the types of the numbers. Examples:

- `1 + 2` is `3`, an `Int`, because both `1` and `2` are `Int`s, and `a + b` is an `Int` if both `a` and `b` are `Int`s;
- `1 / 2` is *not* an `Int` even though both `1` and `2` are individually `Int`s, but is instead `1/2` aka `0.5`, a `Rat`.
- `1 + 4 / 2` will *print out* as `3`, but the `3` is internally a *`Rat`*, not an `Int`, due to [Numeric infectiousness](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics#Numeric_infectiousness).

<sup>**[2]**</sup> All that enforcement does is generate a run-time error if you try to assign or bind a value that is not of the numeric type you've specified as the variable's type constraint. Enforcement doesn't mean that Raku will convert numbers for you. You have to write your formulae to ensure the result you get is what you want.<sup>**[1]**</sup> You *can* use coercion -- but coercion cannot regain precision that's already been lost.

Comment: Thank you very much raiph !!! Excellent and clear explanations as always. I have not declared any numeric types as the data I have are from WWW and are mixes of Int, Cools and Strings like "123.45", fractions, floats, and scientific notations, and so I think the results are automatically converted to float. I will make changes accordingly. Thanks !!!